# How to loop through JSON array using PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, yelp

My PHP code:

```
$obj = json_decode($data);
print $obj->{'name'};
```

While it works for non-arrays, I can't for the life of me figure out how to print all the values within the "Reviews" Array.

What I would like to do is to loop through this response, probably with forreach(), resulting in a list containing the rating and excerpt for each review in the response.

Any guidance / direction is greatly appreciated..

Below is the JSON I'm working with. (it is the response from the Yelp API).

```
{
    "is_claimed": true,
    "rating": 4.5,
    "mobile_url": "http://m.yelp.com/biz/economy-paint-and-collision-riverside",
    "rating_img_url": "http://s3-media2.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/99493c12711e/ico/stars/v1/stars_4_half.png",
    "review_count": 19,
    "name": "Economy Paint & Collision",
    "snippet_image_url": "http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/photo/ZOzoahw0Go_DEPLvxCaP_Q/ms.jpg",
    "rating_img_url_small": "http://s3-media2.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/a5221e66bc70/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_4_half.png",
    "url": "http://www.yelp.com/biz/economy-paint-and-collision-riverside",
    "reviews": [
        {
            "rating": 3,
            "excerpt": "The Good:\nDennis quoted me a price over the phone about 1 month before I took my wifes 2010 Escalade in for repairs and when I took it in he gave me the...",
            "time_created": 1357010247,
            "rating_image_url": "http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/34bc8086841c/ico/stars/v1/stars_3.png",
            "rating_image_small_url": "http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/902abeed0983/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_3.png",
            "user": {
                "image_url": "http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/photo/mIsU7ugYd88lLA-XL2q1Cg/ms.jpg",
                "id": "V9MDZvEBv-tBTF4YIoc7mg",
                "name": "Sydney H."
            },
            "rating_image_large_url": "http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/e8b5b79d37ed/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_3.png",
            "id": "HfOhzLIlJoUKSKU8euclqA"
        },
        {
            "rating": 5,
            "excerpt": "Dennis and his team did an amazing job on the roof of my fiancee's 2002 Acura RSX after years of living by the beach in San Francisco had mostly rusted...",
            "time_created": 1354741952,
            "rating_image_url": "http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/f1def11e4e79/ico/stars/v1/stars_5.png",
            "rating_image_small_url": "http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/c7623205d5cd/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_5.png",
            "user": {
                "image_url": "http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/photo/ZOzoahw0Go_DEPLvxCaP_Q/ms.jpg",
                "id": "kOqCnCjYn0EbAhtH1tfjcw",
                "name": "Jason H."
            },
            "rating_image_large_url": "http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/22affc4e6c38/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_5.png",
            "id": "YzZg1LX6zeRaurq9tYUcMw"
        },
        {
            "rating": 5,
            "excerpt": "It's been a year since I had my car painted here, and I gotta say: It still looks just as good as it did when I first picked it up. You would never know...",
            "time_created": 1361043626,
            "rating_image_url": "http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/f1def11e4e79/ico/stars/v1/stars_5.png",
            "rating_image_small_url": "http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/c7623205d5cd/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_5.png",
            "user": {
                "image_url": "http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/photo/58coTtu1x5riHSgFEAQsfw/ms.jpg",
                "id": "kVrW3138d5VL-AZ97wFF4A",
                "name": "Jeanne M."
            },
            "rating_image_large_url": "http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/22affc4e6c38/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_5.png",
            "id": "r5WtlQVMXiIMBR6S3N7RZw"
        }
    ],
    "phone": "9517870227",
    "snippet_text": "Dennis and his team did an amazing job on the roof of my fiancee's 2002 Acura RSX after years of living by the beach in San Francisco had mostly rusted...",
    "image_url": "http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/kodoEcmgHRG61pPaWRndbw/ms.jpg",
    "categories": [
        [
            "Body Shops",
            "bodyshops"
        ],
        [
            "Auto Repair",
            "autorepair"
        ]
    ],
    "display_phone": "+1-951-787-0227",
    "rating_img_url_large": "http://s3-media4.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/9f83790ff7f6/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_4_half.png",
    "id": "economy-paint-and-collision-riverside",
    "is_closed": false,
    "location": {
        "city": "Riverside",
        "display_address": [
            "2548 Rubidoux Blvd",
            "Riverside, CA 92509"
        ],
        "geo_accuracy": 8,
        "postal_code": "92509",
        "country_code": "US",
        "address": [
            "2548 Rubidoux Blvd"
        ],
        "coordinate": {
            "latitude": 34.0132437,
            "longitude": -117.3923804
        },
        "state_code": "CA"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are probably having trouble because reviews is an array and you are trying to access it as a JSON object.

```
$obj = json_decode($data, TRUE);
for($i=0; $i<count($obj['reviews']); $i++) {
    echo "Rating is " . $obj['reviews'][$i]["rating"] . " and the excerpt is " . $obj['reviews'][$i]["excerpt"] . "<BR>";
}
```

Comment: how would you get things lower in the data, like user "image_url"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want but I guess you want print it just for debugging right now. You can try with `print_r($obj);` and `var_dump($obj);` - they must print something, especially `var_dump()`.
When you see the data, you can easily edit function a little bit, so you can do for instance `print_r($obj->reviews)` or `print_r($obj['reviews'])`, depending if `$obj` is object or array.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, what I am trying to do is to simply print / echo the rating and excerpt for all entities within the reviews array. I am lost on how to print / echo this data alone, without everything else

Answer (score 0):

You can use var_dump or print_r.

```
<?php 
$decodedJSON = json_decode($jsonData);

// Put everyting to the screen with var_dump;
var_dump($decodedJSON);

// With print_r ( useful for arrays );
print_r($decodedJSON);

// List just review ratings with foreach;
foreach($decodedJSON['reviews'] as $review){
    echo $review['rating'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here using objects example (to read reviews...raiting):

```
$jsonObject = json_decode($data);
foreach ($jsonObject->reviews as $data) {
    echo $data->rating;
}
```