# How to loop through these values in PHP

Tags: php

**How to to loop through the   json_decode($json_emp)    output in PHP and get the values ?**

```
    $array_emp = json_decode($json_emp);
    var_dump( $array_emp)

        {"info":[{"id":"10","name":"employee1"},{"id":"11","name":"employee2"},{"id":"12","name":"emplyee3"}]}
```

Need to find get the individual values of ID and name . Here is the array.

`$array_emp = json_decode($json_emp,true);`

```
Array
(
    [info] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [name] => employee1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 11
                    [name] => employee2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12
                    [name] => emplyee3
                )

        )

)
```

Here is the objects ;

```
stdClass Object
(
    [info] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [name] => employee1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 11
                    [name] => employee2
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 12
                    [name] => emplyee3
                )

        )

)
```

Please let me know how to loop through these and get the values . Tried a lot and got confused .

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: And another: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15607029/1065197

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use objects, try this:

```
foreach ($array_tmp->info as $emp)
{
    echo $emp->name;
}
```

For arrays:

```
foreach  ($array_tmp['info'] as $emp)
{
    echo $emp['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$json = '{"info":[{"id":"10","name":"employee1"},{"id":"11","name":"employee2"},{"id":"12","name":"emplyee3"}]}';

$json = json_decode($json, TRUE);
foreach($json['info'] as $info){
    echo 'ID: '.$info['id'].PHP_EOL;    
    echo 'Name: '.$info['name'].PHP_EOL;    
}
```

above code outputs

```
ID: 10
Name: employee1
ID: 11
Name: employee2
ID: 12
Name: emplyee3
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/yKOHtT)**

and if you process `object` rather than `array`

```
$json = json_decode($json);
foreach($json->info as $info){
    echo 'ID: '.$info->id.PHP_EOL;  
    echo 'Name: '.$info->name.PHP_EOL;  
}
```

will output the same as above.

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/axko9P)**